# Убрать день из интервала

Tags: php, массивы

Интервал взят из текстового бокса в определенном формате. Беру начало и конец интервала.

Как убрать один день из средины этого интервала?

К примеру, интервал: `01-02-2016 - 01-03-2016`, и нужно убрать `26-02-2016`.

Данный код считает дни. Если будний день является выходным, он не должен браться в расчёт. В этом загвоздка.

Я так понимаю, нужно каким-то образом удалять конкретные даты?

```
/* Расчет количества дней */

$dateStart = new DateTime( $rangePickerStart ); // Дата начала расчета
$dateEnd = new DateTime( $rangePickerEnd ); // Дата окончания расчета   

$daysStudy = $_POST['input']; // Массив, в который заносятся выбранные 
  //дни недели из формы. 0 это воскресенье                  
$allDaysStudy = 0;


while ( $dateStart <= $dateEnd )
    {
        if ( in_array( $dateStart->format( 'w' ), $daysStudy ) )
            $allDaysStudy++;
        $dateStart-> modify( '+1 day' );

    }

echo "Количество всех выбраных дней недели в заданном диапазоне дат: <b>",
  $allDaysStudy, "</b>\n";
echo "<br/>";
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Предположим, что `$datesToExclude` содержит даты, которые надо исключить.
Тогда:

```
/* Расчет количества дней */

$dateStart = new DateTime( $rangePickerStart ); // Дата начала расчета
$dateEnd = new DateTime( $rangePickerEnd ); // Дата окончания расчета   

$daysStudy = $_POST['input']; // Массив, в который заносятся выбранные 
  //дни недели из формы. 0 это воскресенье                  
$allDaysStudy = 0;

$datesInRange = Array(); // здесь будем хранить полный набор дат

while ( $dateStart <= $dateEnd )
{
    if ( in_array( $dateStart->format( 'w' ), $daysStudy ) ) {
        $allDaysStudy++;
    }
    // если текущей даты нет в архиве на исключение - добавляем в список дат
    if (!in_array($dateStart->format('d-m-Y'), $datesToExclude)) {
        $datesInRange[] = $dateStart->format('d-m-Y');
    }
    $dateStart-> modify( '+1 day' );
}
```

*Замечание*: здесь важен формат дат. Т.е., чтобы код правильно работал, даты в массиве `$datesToExclude` должны быть в формате 'd-m-Y'.